# porting THINC Server to Android platform

Tags: android, c++, c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to port the THINC server code which is available for linux(see link below),

http://systems.cs.columbia.edu/projects/thinc/       THINC server is based on X11.

Please help me out the possibilities of porting THINC Server to Android platform.

and  how to capture screen using OpenGL ES on Android.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to cross compile your code for android platform, so you need proper tool chain to be installed in your linux PC to cross compile.